# Google app engine transaction granularity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, objectify

I am writing a java application on Google App Engine(GAE) using objectify for datastore interface. I need to use transaction to make sure some of the operations in my app are atomic.  But I am confused about granularity of the database transaction i.e. if I am using a particular entity object in a transaction in a thread then which one of the following is true ? :-

1) Can I use some other object of the same entity in a transaction in a different thread concurrently ?

2) OR, Is it that at a time I can be making changes to only one object of a particular entity type

If (2) is true, then what should I do if I expect to have multiple request to be coming for updating a particular entity type even though they will be for different objects under that entity type ?

Thanks...

Comment: As I understand it when you are inside a transaction you are seeing a snapshot of the database, taken at the moment you entered the transaction. In python you can have a cross entity transaction that deals with (IIRC) up to 5 entity types.

Comment: What use would it be if you could only update a single entity of the same type concurrently? Obviously that isn't the case. What piece of documentation made you think it was?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Thanks Daniel for your response! Actually lack of any documentation mentioning this explicitly made me put in doubt. I thought that may be transaction have granularity at entity type level i.e. only one transaction can work on a particular entity type at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section on Optimistic Concurrency here:

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts#Transactions